# How to merge arrays based on deep value?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [OrderProduct] => Array (
            [pro_code] => B1
            [totalQTY] => 4
        )
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [OrderProduct] => Array (
            [pro_code] => B2
            [totalQTY] => 4
        )
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [OrderProduct] => Array (
            [pro_code] => B4
            [totalQTY] => 4
        )
    )
)
```

---

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [OrderProduct] => Array (
            [pro_code] => B1
            [totalDistSalesQTY] => 360
        )
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [OrderProduct] => Array (
            [pro_code] => B2
            [totalDistSalesQTY] => 600
        )
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [OrderProduct] => Array (
            [pro_code] => B3
            [totalDistSalesQTY] => 600
        )
    )
)
```

I would like to merge the two arrays above on the `pro_code` value.  This is the expected result:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [OrderProduct] => Array (
            [pro_code] => B1
            [totalDistSalesQTY] => 360
            [totalQTY] => 4
        )
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [OrderProduct] => Array (
            [pro_code] => B2
            [totalDistSalesQTY] => 600
            [totalQTY] => 4
        )
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [OrderProduct] => Array (
            [pro_code] => B3
            [totalDistSalesQTY] => 600
        )
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [OrderProduct] => Array (
            [pro_code] => B4
            [totalQTY] => 4
        )
    )
)
```

I want to merge multiple array. Please help me to merge it properly.  I applied many techniques to merge it. Still I could not find my way. Please help me with this issue.

Comment: What did you tried ???

Comment: And, at last, what do you really want?

Comment: Do you try with array_diff() =>  http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php  ?

Answer (score 1):

So basically, what you have to do, is implement a [merge algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm#Merging_two_lists) on a sequence. It is one of the basic programming theses, so it shouldn't be too hard.

First, you have to sort the sequences in ascending order (the arrays in the example) by a unique, strictly sortable value (this is the `pro_code` in here).

Second, you need to iterate through both sequences at the same time.
If the current items unique key (`pro_code`) match, merge them and push to the result array, if not push the one with the lesser key to the result array. After pushing, increase the index of the pushed sequence by one.

After reaching the end of one of the sequences, push the rest to the result array.

And this is how it looks implemented in php:

```
<?php

//  Compare func for usort
function compare($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['OrderProduct']['pro_code'], $b['OrderProduct']['pro_code']);

}

//  Sort array with usort
function sort_array(&$a) {
    usort($a, 'compare');

}

//  Print array
function print_a(&$a) {
    print '<pre>';
    print_r($a);
    print '</pre>';

}

function list_merge(&$a,  &$b) {
    $resp = array();

    $ia = 0;
    $ib = 0;
    while($ia < count($a) || $ib < count($b)) {
        //  Check if any of the arrays reached its end
        //  If not, check for merge
        if(isset($a[$ia]) && isset($b[$ib])) {
            //  Product codes are matching, 
            //  Push merged to $resp
            if(strcmp($a[$ia]['OrderProduct']['pro_code'], $b[$ib]['OrderProduct']['pro_code']) == 0) {
                $resp[] = array(
                    'OrderProduct'  => array(
                            'pro_code'  => $a[$ia]['OrderProduct']['pro_code'],
                            'totalQTY'  => $a[$ia]['OrderProduct']['totalQTY'] + $b[$ib]['OrderProduct']['totalQTY'],
                    ),
                );

                //  If merge increment both
                $ia++;
                $ib++;

            }
            //  Product code of element of $a is lesser,
            //  Push $a to $resp
            elseif(strcmp($a[$ia]['OrderProduct']['pro_code'], $b[$ib]['OrderProduct']['pro_code']) < 0) {
                $resp[] = array(
                    'OrderProduct'  => array(
                            'pro_code'  => $a[$ia]['OrderProduct']['pro_code'],
                            'totalQTY'  => $a[$ia]['OrderProduct']['totalQTY'],
                    ),
                );

                //  Increment only pushed
                $ia++;

            }
            //  Product code of element of $b is lesser,
            //  Push $b to $resp
            else {
                $resp[] = array(
                    'OrderProduct'  => array(
                            'pro_code'  => $b[$ib]['OrderProduct']['pro_code'],
                            'totalQTY'  => $b[$ib]['OrderProduct']['totalQTY'],
                    ),
                );

                //  Increment only pushed
                $ib++;

            }

        }
        //  Else automatically push the existing array
        //  If $a exists
        elseif(isset($a[$ia])) {
            $resp[] = array(
                'OrderProduct'  => array(
                        'pro_code'  => $a[$ia]['OrderProduct']['pro_code'],
                        'totalQTY'  => $a[$ia]['OrderProduct']['totalQTY'],
                ),
            );

            //  Increment only pushed
            $ia++;

        }
        //  Else automatically push the existing array
        //  If $b exists
        else {
            $resp[] = array(
                'OrderProduct'  => array(
                        'pro_code'  => $b[$ib]['OrderProduct']['pro_code'],
                        'totalQTY'  => $b[$ib]['OrderProduct']['totalQTY'],
                ),
            );

            //  Increment only pushed
            $ib++;

        }

    }

    return $resp;

}


//  Data structures
$array1 = array(
    array(
        'OrderProduct'  => array(
                'pro_code'  => 'B1',
                'totalQTY'  => 4,
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'OrderProduct'  => array(
                'pro_code'  => 'B2',
                'totalQTY'  => 4,
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'OrderProduct'  => array(
                'pro_code'  => 'B4',
                'totalQTY'  => 4,
        ),
    ),
);

$array2 = array(
    array(
        'OrderProduct'  => array(
                'pro_code'  => 'B1',
                'totalQTY'  => 360,
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'OrderProduct'  => array(
                'pro_code'  => 'B2',
                'totalQTY'  => 600,
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'OrderProduct'  => array(
                'pro_code'  => 'B3',
                'totalQTY'  => 600,
        ),
    ),
);


//  Sort arrays by product code
sort_array($array1);
sort_array($array2);

//  Merge arrays with list merge
$array3 = list_merge($array1, $array2);

//  Print arrays for check
print_a($array1);
print_a($array2);
print_a($array3);
```

I hope, I could be of any help.

Answer (score 1):

This is as condensed as I can make my method.  It is effectively 3 simple steps with a custom function.

Code:

```
$QTY=[
    ["OrderProduct"=>
        ["pro_code"=>"B1","totalQTY"=>"4"]],
    ["OrderProduct"=>
        ["pro_code"=>"B2","totalQTY"=>"4"]],
    ["OrderProduct"=>
        ["pro_code"=>"B4","totalQTY"=>"4"]]
];
$DSQTY=[
    ["OrderProduct" =>
        ["pro_code"=>"B1","totalDistSalesQTY"=>"360"]],
    ["OrderProduct"=>
        ["pro_code"=>"B2","totalDistSalesQTY"=>"600"]],
    ["OrderProduct"=>
        ["pro_code"=>"B3","totalDistSalesQTY"=>"600"]]
];

function getDeepColumn($a,$c,$result=[]){
    foreach(array_column(array_column($a,"OrderProduct"),$c,'pro_code') as $k=>$v){
        $result[$k][$c]=$v;
    }
    return $result;
}

$merged=array_merge_recursive(getDeepColumn($QTY,'totalQTY'),getDeepColumn($DSQTY,'totalDistSalesQTY'));
ksort($merged);  // make sure B4 is not before B3
foreach($merged as $k=>$a){
    $result[]=["OrderProduct"=>array_merge(["pro_code"=>$k],$a)];
}
var_export($result);
```

Custom function explanation:  `getDeepColumn()` uses [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) with a nominated array and a nominated column name to extract the desired values from all `OrderProduct` subarrays. The column values are temporarily stored in an array of arrays called `$result`.  `$result`'s first level keys are `pro_code` values for future merging purposes.  `$result`'s subarrays consist of the nominated column's name (as key) and the nominated column's value (as values).

First, use [array_merge_recursive()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) to blend together the desired deep column values.

Next, `$merge` is [ksort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)'ed (using the unique `pro_code` keys).

Finally, using [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), re-index all `OrderProduct` subarrays, and return the `pro_code` value to its rightful place inside the `OrderProduct` subarray.

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'OrderProduct' => 
    array (
      'pro_code' => 'B1',
      'totalQTY' => '4',
      'totalDistSalesQTY' => '360',
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'OrderProduct' => 
    array (
      'pro_code' => 'B2',
      'totalQTY' => '4',
      'totalDistSalesQTY' => '600',
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'OrderProduct' => 
    array (
      'pro_code' => 'B3',
      'totalDistSalesQTY' => '600',
    ),
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'OrderProduct' => 
    array (
      'pro_code' => 'B4',
      'totalQTY' => '4',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple if you use the product code as a key in the result array.

```
// combine the two arrays together and iterate all their rows
foreach (array_merge($array1, $array2) as $row) {

    // get the code
    $code = $row['OrderProduct']['pro_code'];

    // get the previous value for that code, or an empty array if there isnt' one
    $prev = $result[$code]['OrderProduct'] ?? [];

    // merge the previous value with the new value
    $result[$code]['OrderProduct'] = array_merge($prev, $row['OrderProduct']);
}
```

You'll end up with product code keys in your result array, which is probably fine. If it's *not* fine, you can remove them with `$result = array_values($result)`.